# JTextArea with a Title?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, text-align

Using JTextArea, I would like for the first line to be a simple text (Title of the JTextArea).

Is there a way to make the text center align on the first line?

Comment: It this area is not intended to be editable, I'd use a HTML formatted `JLabel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a simple `JTextArea`.  You might consider switching to a [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html), which supports HTML markup.  The Java Tutorial [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) shows an example.

Alternatively, you can just add a `JLabel` above your `JTextArea` where you display the title text.